# Cannot compare string with IEnumerable Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an entity method which I don´t want to change:

**Listar method**

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> Listar(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _dbset;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).AsEnumerable<T>();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.AsEnumerable<T>();
            }
        }
```

and I use into the query like

```
var vehiculo = _pService.Listar(x => x.TipoContenedor.CatalogosID.Equals("TCO"), includeProperties: "TipoContenedor").Select(x => x.TipoContenedor.Nombre);
```

**Table:**

```
public class TipoVehiculo: Entidad<Int32>
    {
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string CapacidadCarga { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string CapacidadCubica { get; set; }

        public int TipoContenedorID { get; set; }
        public CatalogoRegistro TipoContenedor { get; set; }
        public int EstatusID { get; set; }
        public Estatus Estatus { get; set; }

    }
```

Problem is when I want to use select `.Select(x => x.TipoContenedor.Nombre)`, because when I try to use query with mapper like:

```
  var vehiculo = _pService.Listar(x => x.TipoContenedor.CatalogosID.Equals("TCO"), includeProperties: "TipoContenedor").Select(x => x.TipoContenedor.Nombre);


  IEnumerable<TipoVehiculoViewModel> est = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TipoVehiculo>, IEnumerable<TipoVehiculoViewModel>>(vehiculo);

  response = request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<TipoVehiculoViewModel>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, est);
```

I get an error into vehiculo saying:

> Argument type System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable is not
>   assignable to parameter type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

What do I need to do to send only table column of `INNERJOIN`?

NOTE: That innerjoin is because I use include properties of TipoContenedor so EF interprets it as innerjoin with that table.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Nombre] AS [Nombre], 
[Extent1].[CapacidadCarga] AS [CapacidadCarga], 
[Extent1].[CapacidadCubica] AS [CapacidadCubica], 
[Extent1].[TipoContenedorID] AS [TipoContenedorID], 
[Extent1].[EstatusID] AS [EstatusID], 
[Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
[Extent2].[Codigo] AS [Codigo], 
[Extent2].[Nombre] AS [Nombre1], 
[Extent2].[PadreID] AS [PadreID], 
[Extent2].[CatalogosID] AS [CatalogosID], 
[Extent2].[FechaCreacion] AS [FechaCreacion], 
[Extent2].[UsuarioCreacionID] AS [UsuarioCreacionID], 
[Extent2].[FechaModificacion] AS [FechaModificacion], 
[Extent2].[UsuarioModificacionID] AS [UsuarioModificacionID], 
[Extent2].[EstatusRegistro] AS [EstatusRegistro]
FROM  [adm].[TiposVehiculo] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [adm].[Catalogos_Registros] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TipoContenedorID] = [Extent2].[ID]
WHERE N'TCO' = [Extent2].[CatalogosID]
```

Column I want is `[Extent2].[Nombre] AS [Nombre1]`, which is from innerjoin clause

Comment: isn't your vehiculo variable an IEnumerable<string> ? What's TipoVehiculoViewModel ?

Comment: Possibly you want to pass `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<TipoVehiculo>` or `IEnumerable<TipoVehiculoViewModel>` which has similar `IEnumerable` object but with different type parameter.

Comment: and what about if I want to pass more than one column, and pass into an object, how can I do a select with 2 columns? like: `Select(x => new
                {
                    x.TipoContenedor.ID,
                    x.TipoContenedor.Nombre
                });` it can´t be an string, what I need to do there? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: I found solution, I send as an object like  `IEnumerable<object> est = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<object>, IEnumerable<object>>(vehiculo);`